# Baffled by loops - any help welcome

Tags: javascript, loops, repeat

I’m struggling with making Javascript repeat this code block. It's for a code-operated Phidget switch and works just the once to turn an electronic relay on and off (with a timer for duration) ("Phidget22" is the Node package specific to the device).

I can't find a working method to make the process repeat itself.

Below is the working code, with explanatory notes for what the stages do.

```
var phidget22 = require('phidget22');

function runExample() {
    //Create your Phidget channels
    var digitalOutput0 = new phidget22.DigitalOutput();

    //Set addressing parameters to specify which channel to open (if any)
    digitalOutput0.setHubPort(2);
    digitalOutput0.setDeviceSerialNumber(606877);

    //Assign any event handlers you need before calling open so that no events are missed.

    //Open your Phidgets and wait for attachment
    digitalOutput0.open(5000).then(function() {

        //Do stuff with your Phidgets here or in your event handlers.
        digitalOutput0.setDutyCycle(1);

        setTimeout(function () {
            //Close your Phidgets once the program is done.
            digitalOutput0.close();
            process.exit(0);
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get the idea, but perhaps [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) would work for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply and have dabbled with a few of these - but can't seem to find the right position in that code to place stuff. Will keep reading up and persevering! :)